# Strtotime range

Tags: php, datetime, datepicker, strtotime

Good evening,
I have to admit I do not know php very well. In fact, I'm a beginner,
I would like some help with the following code.

At this time, if you place an order with a begin_valability today, you receive the message "Minimum accepted start date_valability" is tomorrow "and it is OK.

I would like to be unable to place any orders if the begin_valability value is greater than

2017-12-31.

Thank you in advance

```
#defined API * required


if (isset ($this -> _ params ['begin_valability'])) {
            
if ($this -> _ params ['begin_valability']! = null) {

#validate if begin_valability is valid
                
if ($this-> validateDate ($this -> _ params, 'Y-m-d') == false) {
                    WebApp_Mobile_Messages :: error ( '125');
                   return;
                }
                
                
$today = date("Y-m-d");
if ($today> = $this -> _ params ['begin_valability']) {
WebApp_Mobile_Messages :: error (0, "Minimum accepted start date_valability" . date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day" )));
                    
return;
                }
             }
```

Comment: What is the value of `$this -> _ params ['begin_valability']`?

Comment: It's a start date like this 2017-12-14

Answer (score 0):

PHP DateTime instances are comparable.

A datetime string can be converted to a DateTime instance in various ways amongst which is passing said datetime string as a argument to initialize a new DateTime object.

```
$yearEnd = new DateTime('2017-12-31');

$beginValability = new DateTime($this->_params['begin_valability']);
```

Add a guard clause before placing orders:

```
if ($beginValability > $yearEnd) return;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider either converting dates to either [DateTime objects](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) or [strtotime integer values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). It will then be possible to easily compare two different dates.

Example:

```
/* Defines before class definition */
define('MIN_VALABILITY_DATE_INTERVAL', strtotime('+1 days')); /* 1 day interval (as int) */
define('MAX_VALABILITY_DATE_STATIC', strtotime('2017-12-31')); /* Max specific date (as int) */
define('MAX_VALABILITY_DATE_INTERVAL', strtotime('+10 days')); /* 10 day interval (as int) */

/* ...function() */

    if(!empty($this->_params['begin_valability'])){
        if($this->validateDate($this->_params['begin_valability'], 'Y-m-d')){
            $begin_valability = strtotime($this->_params['begin_valability']);
            if($begin_valability >= MIN_VALABILITY_DATE_INTERVAL && $begin_valability <= MAX_VALABILITY_DATE_STATIC){
                /* succsess - do something */
            }else /* date out of range */{
                WebApp_Mobile_Messages::error('');
            }
        }else /* invalid date */{
            WebApp_Mobile_Messages::error('125');
        }
    }else /* begin_valability is empty */{
        WebApp_Mobile_Messages::error('');
    }
    return;

/* function end */
```

**EDIT:** *Obviously there's is no need to use those defines and it's probably better to use local variables if those values aren't going to be referenced elsewhere.*

Comment: tomorrow I will test and come back with feedback